# Use interface to get response from another class

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire

I'm making my request with Alamofire lib and I have a class for requests like Login,Register,... so I need an interface to notice when Alamofire receives responses. How can I do that in swift?

this is part of my Trans.swift

```
class Trans{
func getToken(username: String , password: String){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.shafadoc.ir/api/DocApp/Token?value=" + username + ":" + password ,parameters:nil)
        .responseJSON{ response in
            if let json = response.result.value{
            }
    }
}
}
```

and my LoginViewController:

```
  if !login_password.text!.isEmpty || !login_username.text!.isEmpty
    {
        var trans : Trans = Trans
        trans.getToken(login_username.text!, password: login_password.text!)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block passed to `.responseJSON` method is where you are notified when the request completes. You can pass a callback block in `trans.getToken` and call the block inside `.responseJSON`. Like this:

```
func getToken(username: String , password: String, completion: Void -> Void){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.shafadoc.ir/api/DocApp/Token?value=" + username + ":" + password ,parameters:nil)
        .responseJSON{ response in
            if let json = response.result.value{
            }
            //... do anything you want with the result, and finally:
            completion()    // <-- call the block
    }
}
```

In your view controller:

```
if !login_password.text!.isEmpty || !login_username.text!.isEmpty
{
    var trans : Trans = Trans
    trans.getToken(login_username.text!, password: login_password.text!) {
        //... do your UI stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post an example for that? Im making my request in a Login method i LoginViewController and requests are in Trans.swift

Comment: but how can i receive response in my UI controller?

Comment: If you want to pass the respons JSON to your controller, change the completion handler to `AnyObject -> Void`, and call `completion(json)`

Comment: hi, tnx. please change || to && in you if condition. ;)